# After sending a message in Cyrillic from contact form, I receive messages but not in Cyrillic PHP

Tags: javascript, php, email, contact-form, cyrillic

After sending a message in Cyrillic from contact form, I receive messages but not in Cyrillic. I try to put a encoding in html, try whats on Stack Overflow, I still can't make it. Here is the data of my PHP file

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
    // Prepare the email
    $to = 'mail@abv.bg';

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mail_from = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = 'Message sent from website';
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $header = "From: $name <$mail_from>";

    // Send it
    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
    if($sent) {
        echo 'Вашето съобщение беше изпратено успешно!';
    } else {
        echo 'Съжаляваме,но вашето съобщение не може да бъде изпратено.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where did you try to put the encoding? Try doing `$header  = [ "From: $name <$mail_from>", "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8" ]`

Comment: it doesn't work , i tried like $headers = ."Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8";

Comment: i dont recieve email from you code

Comment: You did not try what I suggested.  I suggested an array of 2 entries. You just did one of the two

Comment: i tried it, and no message receive

Comment: else {
   echo 'Съжаляваме,но вашето съобщение не може да бъде изпратено.';
   }

Comment: that means sorry, your message cant be send

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each page (both the form and the action/receiver) use the same encoding (UTF-8, or the extended ASCII you prefer, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251).

In some cases, PHP has a separate user config file (I guess, telling the PHP interpreter among other things, what encoding to use, which somehow ignores the page header).

So there is a global `php.ini`, often inaccessible by users on a shared hosting. There is also a user-based config file, so on your server check for a config file outside the `public_html` folder. I don't remember what the file is called, it's self-descriptive though.
Set encoding in that file, then Bob's your auntie.